# Nestjs - middleware not triggered on OPTIONS request

Tags: typescript, nestjs

When sending `OPTIONS` request, middleware doesn't get triggered.

```
export class AppModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(CorsMiddleware).forRoutes({
      path: "*",
      method: RequestMethod.OPTIONS
    });
  }
}
```

If I were to change `RequestMethod.OPTIONS` to `RequestMethod.ALL`, it would get triggered on all requests, except `OPTIONS`.

Is that by design? If so, how do we workaround it when we want to specifically trigger middleware for `OPTIONS` request.

Example middleware:

```
@Injectable()
export class CorsMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  resolve(...args: any[]): MiddlewareFunction {
    return (req, res, next) => {
      console.log("testing ", req.method);
      next && next();
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this might be better suited as an issue if you have a minimal repo to reproduce it with. https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues

Comment: Is there a different middlware already active that intercepts OPTIONS ?

Comment: In fact, it appears it's impossible to handle preflights requests in Nestjs at all

Comment: We handle CORS using interceptor without a problem.

Comment: @KarolSamborski can you provide example of your interceptor and which Nestjs version are you using?

Comment: @Kunok We are on NestJS 6. About an example I'll try to prepare something later.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using middleware you can try adding interceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class CorsInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
    intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
        const request: IncomingMessage = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        const response: ServerResponse = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();

        if ('access-control-request-headers' in request.headers) {
            response.setHeader('access-control-request-headers', request.headers['access-control-request-headers']);
        }

        if ('access-control-request-method' in request.headers) {
            response.setHeader('access-control-request-method', request.headers['access-control-request-method']);
        }

        response.setHeader('access-control-allow-origin', '*');

        return next.handle();
    }
}
```

In order to use it you need also add a decorator above your controller class:

```
@UseInterceptors(CorsInterceptor)
export class SimpleController {
}
```